# How to measure and display the time taken for shinyServer?

Tags: r, shiny

I would like to measure and display on the time taken for the shiny server to execute `shinyServer(function(input, output){}`  for each session on the generated page.

My naive way of doing so is:

```
shinyServer(function(input, output){
  startTime <- proc.time()
  ...
  output$a <- renderPrint({
        print(do.a())
  })
  output$b <- renderPrint({
        print(do.b())
  })
  ...
  stopTime <- proc.time()

  output$timeTaken <- renderPrint({
    stopTime - startTime
  })
```

Which gives me wrong value, probably due to lazy evaluation of the code in between.

How to do it properly then?

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the contents of the function `system.time`, or using a profiling package like `profr` or `proftools`?

Comment: I meant inside the function, that is, `shinyServer(function(input, output){system.time(some stuff)})`.

Comment: @RichieCotton Wouldn't wrapping generate a scope and thus hide all my outputs?

Comment: Not an answer, but as an FYI: we are thinking about how to add this kind of inspection to the reactive process in base Shiny. I'll let you know if I think of a good work-around in the mean-time, however!

Comment: @Jeff Allen I am currently looking for the same functionality. Has there been any progress on this?